# Nested ngRepeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a Table Data with column heading defined in a scope variable (which is not static) and and List of rows to display.

[Plunker URL]

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZR6uIL3pXffLqem3h06r?p=preview
```

It looks like the field value is not getting resolved in the expression `{{row.field}}`.

Thanks

Comment: Some code would be appreciated

Comment: sorry missed the plunker URL in my earlier post. Added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct expression should be `{{row[field]}}`